# Does ac **av and argc, *argv[] do the same thing in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

`ac` and `av` are passed as argument to `main` function sometimes instead of `argc` and `*argv[]`.

Do they do the same thing?

Comment: do names matter? you could write `int quack` and `char *potato[]`

Answer (score 1):

The names don't matter, the compiler does not care what they are. The only concern is the typing.

You can call them whatever you want, so long as the types match. Note `char** v` and `char* v[]` are equivalent to the compiler.

The convention is `argc` and `argv` which helps your code be more readable and consistent. Unless you have a very compelling reason, stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; the parameter names of `main()` don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just parameter name, you can name them how you want.

But for the main function, I would rather stick to standard naming (argc, argv) rather than ac / av.